# PHP: How to convert single quote to double quote in all HTML tags?

Tags: php, string

How can I convert all single quotes to double quotes in all HTML tags only? Is there an easier way to do it? 
Thanks :)

For example:
How can I convert this string (actual data from my work):

```
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING='2'><P ALIGN='LEFT'><FONT FACE='Verdana' style="font-size:10' COLOR='#0B333C'>My name's Mark</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
```

To this:

```
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Verdana" style="font-size:10" COLOR="#0B333C">My name's Mark</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the JavaScript and CSS issues mentioned elsewhere, try this:

```
$text = "<TEXTFORMAT LEADING='2'><P ALIGN='LEFT'><FONT FACE='Verdana' style='font-size:10' COLOR='#0B333C'>My name's Mark</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>";
echo preg_replace('/<([^<>]+)>/e', '"<" . str_replace("\\\\\'", \'"\', "$1") . ">"', $text);
```

This is taken from a thread by someone with exactly the same problem as you over at [devshed.com](http://forums.devshed.com/regex-programming-147/php-grep-single-to-double-quote-in-tags-595290.html).

Comment: Hi Xiaofu, I tried it but it did not work? Hhhmmm I'll try again :)

Comment: My code example is slightly off though, remember that the updated string is the return value from preg_replace. (updated the answer to reflect this)

Comment: @xiaofu: it worked only using this example code:
$texts = "<p class='essay_caption'>This is Bob's test</p>";
  $zzz = preg_replace('/<([^<>]+)>/e', '"<" . str_replace("\\\\\'", \'"\', "$1") . ">"', $texts);
  echo htmlspecialchars($zzz);

Comment: If you've already taken that into account and it still doesn't work, please let me know and I'll delete the answer.

Comment: @Xiaofu  I want to convert double quotes into single quotes how can I change the above preg_Replace? please advice

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that when you say in all html tags, that you mean all single quotes that contain an attribute. You wouldn't want `<a onclick="alert('hi')">` converted b/c it would break the code.

**Any regular expression is going to be fragile.** If you know your input will be a particular set of simple cases, **you might be ok with a regex**. Otherwise, you'll want a DOM parser that understands complex html markup like `onmouseover="(function () { document.getElementById(''); alert(\"...\")...})()"` (for example). Add to that an attribute can span multiple lines. ;)

I haven't had to tackle this particular problem recently, but maybe there's a good way to do it with [HTML Tidy](http://www.php.net/tidy) (more here: http://devzone.zend.com/article/761) or a parser like this one http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/

Comment: @Keith: In my HTML tags, I don't have any Javascript related code like document.getElementById(''); so I am ok with any regular expression as long as it will solve my problem :D

Thanks, I will check the links you posted.

Comment: any chance that you'll have CSS? such as style="background: url('/images/bg.gif');"

Comment: @Keith: Nope, I will not have a style attribute.

Comment: wait, i see one in your example ;)

Comment: Um, I just converted the 'size="10"' attribute to style="font-size:10px;" but I will not use any single quote inside my HTML tags :)

Comment: i guess that i would start with two regex's one to find everything inside the html tags like this /<([^>]+)>/g, and then for each of those do something like preg_replace("/='([^']*)'/g", '="$1"') ... as a start, hope that helps ... no guarantees, though and i'm out for the night ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Tidy](http://nl2.php.net/tidy) which can fix your HTML soup and output clean XHTML. It does other nice things too, like fixing nesting problems, lowercasing tags, etcetera, etcetera.

Comment: no. [tidy](https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5) does not have this transformation

Answer (score 1):

I know i could hav'e using regex, but give this a try: assign *$string* the contents using *fpen(), fread() etc...*

```
$string = str_replace("'", '"', $string);
$array = explode('>', $string);
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if(strpos($value, '<') <> 0 ){
       $array[$key] = str_replace('"', "'",$value);
    }
}
$string = implode('>',$array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish... Replacing pieces of the string using php can be done using the str_replace function:

```
str_replace("'", "\"", $yourString);
```

Comment: Building on this, you can use PHPs output buffer to callback the entire body and use str replace on it as it were a string.

Comment: They want it to only apply inside HTML tags.

Comment: What happends to "My name's Mark" ?

Comment: @NinethSense - Ah, THAT's what he means...he wants to replace all occurrences of ' with ", but only if they are inside an HTML tag. Perhaps a smart regex can do the trick, but that's not really my expertise.

Comment: Hi Daan, if I do this str_replace("'", "\"", $yourString); then any single quote outside the HTML tag will also get affected, so "My name's Mark" will become "My name"s Mark"

Answer (score 0):

I would go with either a dom parser or roll my own simple tag parser that understands quoting as well as escaping quote characters so that it doesn't take `"he said \"blah\""` as `he said \`, `blah\` and *empty string*.

It could detect whether the quoting to be modified is inside a tag easily. Over many years I have learned that regular expressions are way too fragile for such tasks.